# Oracle tuning for query with query annidate

Tags: oracle, performance, database-performance

i am trying to better a query. I have a dataset of ticket opened. Every ticket has different rows, every row rappresent an update of the ticket. There is a field (dt_update) that differs it every row.

I have this indexs in the st_remedy_full_light. 
IDX_ASSIGNMENT  (ASSIGNMENT)
IDX_REMEDY_INC_ID   (REMEDY_INC_ID)
IDX_REMDULL_LIGHT_DTUPD (DT_UPDATE)

Now, the query is performed in 8 second. Is high for me.

```
WITH last_ticket AS
  ( SELECT *
   FROM st_remedy_full_light a
   WHERE a.dt_update IN
     ( SELECT MAX(dt_update)
       FROM st_remedy_full_light
       WHERE remedy_inc_id = a.remedy_inc_id
     )
  )
SELECT remedy_inc_id, ASSIGNMENT FROM last_ticket
```

This is the plan
[image: Explain Plan]
How i could to better this query?

P.S. This is just a part of a big query

Additional information:
- The table st_remedy_full_light  contain 529.507 rows

Comment: Can be several 'st_remedy_full_light' with the same 'dt_update' per 'remedy_inc_id'?

Comment: an index on (remedy_inc_id, dt_update) - or possibly even (remedy_inc_id, dt_update, assignment) - ought to help you, if you don't want to/can't change the subquery to what Tony Andrews suggests. I.e. a single index containing multiple columns, rather than an index for each column - Oracle will only be able to use one of those single column indexes for the query, it can't use all three even though you're using all three columns in your query. Such an index would probably help Tony Andrew's suggested query too.

Comment: @EvgeniyK. no only remedy_inc_id have more dt_update but not the other.

Comment: @Boneist  I had not thought to use multiple indexs. Work it a few better with  (remedy_inc_id, dt_update, assignment) . But is strange that it use the index only for take the fields in select and not for where condition in subquery

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
WITH last_ticket AS
  ( SELECT remedy_inc_id, ASSIGNMENT,
           rank() over (partition by remedy_inc_id order by dt_update desc) rn
   FROM st_remedy_full_light a
  )
SELECT remedy_inc_id, ASSIGNMENT FROM last_ticket 
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for your reply...Unfortunately i used this solution, but 
strangely is slower than my solution.

Comment: Can you please share more details on why this query will run fast compared to original one .

Comment: @NzGuy I would _expect_ it to _probably_ run faster because it doesn't have to hash join `last_ticket` to itself.

Comment: @vecio88 What does the plan look like when you use this query?

Comment: @TonyAndrews Thanks for sharing details . If the table contains 1 billion records then will this query give same kind of boost as `rn` wont be having any index utilization .

Comment: Since the query has no where clause and no joins, no index utilization is expected.  A full scan is what is required.  If you added an index on `(remedy_inc_id, ASSIGNMENT, dt_update)` then Oracle could full scan that instead of the table, which would be quicker if the index is much smaller than the table.

Comment: @TonyAndrews i look the cost, and the use of the indexs for the join.

Answer (score 1):

The best alternative query, which is also much easier to execute, is this:

```
select remedy_inc_id
     , max(assignment) keep (dense_rank last order by dt_update)
  from st_remedy_full_light
 group by remedy_inc_id
```

This will use only one full table scan and a (hash/sort) group by, no self joins.

Don't bother about indexed access, as you'll probably find a full table scan is most appropriate here. Unless the table is really wide and a composite index on all columns used (remedy_inc_id,dt_update,assignment) would be significantly quicker to read than the table.